# A user insists on making a detrimental edit to one of my posts. What do I do?

Tags: discussion, editing, moderation

Twice today a user has taken it upon him/herself to edit my post to remove what I think is a useful piece of visual information (the cover of a book which also has a graph that I make repeated reference to in the post). This user's edits don't have to pass the review queue because s/he has sufficient rep. Yet the user continues to override my reversion of the edits.

What should I do? I don't think a war of edits is particularly helpful. The user has not attempted to contact me to discuss the issue, so I can't tag him/her in a comment.

Comment: I have located the problem post and rolled it back for you.  I have also edited it to address the problem pointed out by your persistent revisionist; namely, that the image was large.  There's a nice trick: append "s", "m", or "l" to the base name of the imgur URL to change the size automatically.  I appended "m" to shrink it to a readable but hardly objectionable size.  I could also "lock" the post to prevent changes for a specified period of time, but since that also prevents voting, I hesitate to do that to you.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your diligence. I'm afraid that you'll get an unnecessary flag from me in a few seconds, since I flagged it as per your answer. Great tip about resizing images! I'll keep that mind in the future. Thank you. Locking the post for 24 h wouldn't harm me on this particular day, since I've already hit the rep cap. We can see what happens and adapt accordingly.

Comment: While this was resolved, I'd like to add that the editor concerned, not myself, appears to have been attempting in entirely good faith to improve the presentation as they saw it. The editing was not in any sense malign. Competent and conscientious posters here can disagree amicably on what is acceptable and what should be omitted in a presentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The preferred solution is to flag the moderators,** who have additional tools for limiting edits and, if necessary, limiting the abilities of individual users to interact on this site.

Mods can also create chat rooms and invite anybody--whether or not they have ever posted anything--to a private conversation.  Occasionally this has helped reconcile differences of opinion.